# Installing Hamachi in kali-linux

Tags: hamachi, kali-linux

How to install Hamachi in kali-linux? I can't find any tutorial in the net. Using the official .deb package give me an error.

Comment: what error do you get? missing dependency?

Comment: I solved it. I used apt-get install -f logmein-hamachi

Comment: was about to tell you just that :) good you solved it!

Comment: If it's not available on apt, both `gdebi` and `dpkg` can be used to install .deb files in case you haven't tried them.

Answer (score 0):

1. go to [Hamachi web page](https://secure.logmein.com/labs/)
2. scroll down to **LogMeIn Hamachi for Linux (Beta) command line version**
3. click on **Learn more**
4. click on debian file with .deb extension for your architecture
5. Use:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i
   ```

   to install it.